# Выражение сложение - тип СТРОКА. Надо преобразовать в число

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, функции

Есть функция:

```
function calculator(string) {}
```

Параметр функции строка. Аргументом выступает например: '1 + 2'.
Надо, что бы функция возвращала результат операции.
Прохожу циклом по строке, сохраняю операнды. Но что делать со знаком сложения?
Как мне сохранять его, что бы в последствии использовать его по его же назначению? Знак сохраняется как строка и в итоге получаю NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.

```
function calculator(string) {
  let operands = string.split(' ');
  let num1 = parseInt(operands[0]);
  let num2 = parseInt(operands[2]);
  let operator = operands[1];

  let operators = {
    '+': function(num1, num2) { return num1 + num2 },
    '-': function(num1, num2) { return num1 - num2 },
    '*': function(num1, num2) { return num1 * num2 },
    '/': function(num1, num2) { return num1 / num2 }
  };
```

Comment: Что произойдёт, если пробел или пробелы будут отсутствовать? Бяда...

Comment: @UModeL тоже думал об этом. Но в водных данных об этом ничего не было сказано.